# Unable to access CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on a run app and for some reason when I try access the data to map it out I get an error 
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on the following line

```
let locations = run.locations
```

if I change it to

```
let locations = run?.locations
```

I get the "else{" message in the app but it doesnt crash.

I know the data is there because I confirmed it with Liya.  Not sure why my app doesnt see it.

heres the rest of the code

```
    var run : Run!

    func loadMap() {
    guard
        let locations = run.locations,
        locations.count > 0,
        let region = mapRegion()
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error",
                                          message: "Sorry, this run has no locations saved",
                                          preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
            present(alert, animated: true)
            return
    }
    print("loadMap")
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    mapView.add(polyLine())
}
```

TIA

Comment: You have declared `run` as an implicitly unwrapped optional, but you need to actually assign a value to it, or it will be `nil`. Where do you fetch the data from Core Data and assign the value ?

Comment: Forgive the dumb question as I'm really new at this but isnt that what the first line is doing?  If I try to call run after that, .locations and all the other attributes come up

Comment: No, that line simply declares a variable `run` of type `Run!` (An implicitly unwrapped optional `Run`).  You need to actually assign an instance of `Run` to that variable, otherwise it will be `nil`; which is why you get an crash when you use ! but not when you conditionally unwrap it with ?. You need to perform a fetch against Core Data to retrieve a previously saved `Run` object and assign it to that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno!  Thank you.

okay.  so here it is

deleted

```
    var run : Run!
```

declared an empty array since the fetch returns [Any]

```
    var locations : [Any] = []
```

Add the delegate

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
```

then wrote the fetch data func as an extension with a completion handler

```
extension MapsViewController {
func fetch(completion: (_ complete: Bool) -> ()) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Location")

    do{
        locations = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) //Trys to call CoreData and returns an Array of type [Any] and assigns them to the array of locations
        print("fetched data")
        completion(true)

    } catch {
        debugPrint("could not fetch: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion(false)
    }
}
```